# VPI vpi_put_value on nets

Tags: hardware, verilog

I am trying to force the value of the net through **vpi_put_value** (using c interface of the vpi) but simulation doesn't keep the forced value. During simulation it evaluates the value and I see in gtkwave different value than I forced.
I need the method to force the value for specific times (range of the simulation times) which is not depend on simulator (cvc, icarus etc.).

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `vpiForceFlag` flag to force the value through vpi, and release with `vpiReleaseFlag`.

```
vpi_put_value(sys, &return_val, NULL, vpiForceFlag);
```

Refer to the documentation form any Verilog/SytemVerilog LRM:

- IEEE Std 1364-1995 § 23.23 *vpi_put_value()*
- IEEE std 1364-2001 § 27.32 *vpi_put_value()*
- IEEE std 1364-2005 § 27.32 *vpi_put_value()*
- [IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 38.34 *vpi_put_value()*

You can get the same effect with the Verilog keywords `force` and `release`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using this flag which is not helps.
The value changes despite this flag.

I have found workaround for the issue by listening change of the net and setting it to the correct value every time it changes.

Comment: There might be an additional `force` statement being applited to the net. The onlything that should override the value of something forced is another `force` statement or a `release`. Without seeing your verilog code, it is hard to guess.